# v-img not showing image from folder

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, gridsome

So the last two images are not displaying on my site, the images are located locally in the src/assets/images folder. What am I missing?

```
<template>
  <section id="projects" class="project-section">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <h1>Projects</h1>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="justify-space-around">
        <v-card
          v-for="project in projects"
          :key="project.name"
          max-width="300px"
        >{{ project.image }}
          <v-img class="align-end" width="200" :src="project.image" />
          <v-card-title>{{ project.name }}</v-card-title>
          <v-card-subtitle class="pb-0"> {{ project.tech }}: </v-card-subtitle>

          <v-card-text class="text--primary">
            <div>{{ project.description }}</div>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn color="orange" text :href="project.github">
              Github Repo
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn color="orange" text :href="project.url">
              Live
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Projects",
  data() {
    return {
      projects: [
        {
          name: "Twitch24",
          github: "https://github.com/badbabykosh/twitch24",
          url: "https://twitchtv-81469.firebaseapp.com/",
          tech: "Javascript ES5, requireJS, Bootstrap",
          description:
            "Experimental app built with qunit, pure javascript, AMD module design and requireJS with Bootstrap. Launch it. Select you favorite channels and see when they are online.",
          image: "https://new-thefonso.vercel.app/img/portfolio/fullsize/twitch24.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Pomodoro",
          github: "https://github.com/badbabykosh/pomodoro",
          url: "http://pomodoro.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/",
          tech: "React, Bootstrap",
          description:
            "Experimental application utilizing the D3 and jquery libraries and the Bootstrap framework. Launch it in a new window and play with it for fun. Take a look at the code on github",
          image: "https://new-thefonso.vercel.app/img/portfolio/fullsize/fonsodoro.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Cox Auto Prism",
          github: "",
          url: "https://prs-demo.netlify.com/",
          tech: "React, GraphQL, GatsbyJS, React-strap",
          description:
            "Production application built in React. It's purpose is to demo each React component built for the system. PRISM is a React component library style guide. The library is meant to harmonize look and feel across all cox auto properties.",
          image: "https://new-thefonso.vercel.app/img/portfolio/fullsize/prism_big.png",
        },
        {
          name: "3D Demo 1",
          github: "",
          url: "https://unclefonso-3d-demo-uecg.vercel.app/",
          tech: "React, Spline",
          description:
            "A design created in Figma and ported over to 3D and presented inside a React app for demo purposes.",
          image: "@/assets/images/figma3d.png",
        },
        {
          name: "Covid Tracker",
          github: "",
          url: "https://vue-covid-tracker-theta.vercel.app/",
          tech: "Vue 3, external API",
          description:
            "Experimental api consumer demo. An exercise to explore Vue 3 capabilities.",
          image: "@/assets/images/covid_tracker.png",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.project-section {
  background-color: #d8c593;
}
.v-image {
  border-bottom: #708160 1px solid;
}
</style>
```

Network tab shows: "GET http://localhost:8082/@/assets/images/figma3d.png 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Well not showing could be a couple of reasons. But because the online ones are showing and the local ones not. It is most likely not the correct path to the images. Does the browser give a 404 on that image in your network tab?

Comment: @Wimanicesir yes, I see a 404 (updated post to include this info)

Comment: So the problem is clear. It's not with Vuetify, but with the fact that the image is not where you say it is.

Comment: @rozsazoltan the images ARE where I say they are... "the images are located locally in the src/assets/images folder".  But they are not displaying, hence why I am here.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Your SRC folder is not shared with the Vue app. Even if you reference images, they won't be imported. I have since written a more detailed response.

Comment: What are you using to run the localhost server? Nuxt? Vite? Something else?

Comment: In *data(){retun}}*, use ```require``` And it will look like this ```image: require("@/assets/images/covid_tracker.png")```. Then call it on your image ```:src="project.image"```

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation yep....that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image from the `src` folder will not be published automatically. You cannot simply reference a file in the `src` folder. However, there are several ways to overcome this.

#### Solution

**Use the public folder.** All content in every `public` folder will be included in your application, so if you move the `assets` folder there, you can refer to it as `./assets`.

```html
<img src="./assets/images/figma3d.png">
```

If this is a complex application, I suggest setting the root path so that references to every image or font, etc., will originate from the domain regardless of the current URL.

```html
<base href="/">
```

#### More information

- [Setting the root location with the `<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Comment: Hmmm. I am using Gridsome. So I do not see a "public" folder but I do see a "static" folder....Let me try that. UPDATE:  Bingo. Moving the folder to "static" and referencing as described worked.

Comment: I indeed didn't take into account that you are using "gridsome." However, what I wrote is generally true.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution for Gridsome

https://gridsome.org/docs/images

While reading through the Gridsome documentation, I found information about referencing the `src` folder using the `~` symbol instead of the usual `@`.

> Gridsome has a built-in  component that outputs an optimized progressive image. It also resizes and crops in real-time when developing.
>
> A typical image component will look like this:

```html
<g-image src="~/image.png" width="500"/>
```

> `~` is an alias to `/src/` folder.

#### Summary

Although there are [currently active questions in the code repository](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/60) regarding the solution, I leave this here just as an interesting note.

In Vue applications, [statically stored images and others are always easily reusable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693147/15167500).

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is incorrect. That's where I started before coming to SO.